# How to open a new link with a request using Express and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm making a login script in Node, using a MEAN stack. Currently I can search the database and find the user. However, after I find the user, I'm trying to open a link to the index page, but when my code executes nothing happens. Does anyone know how to open links through a route?

client.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); 
app.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.login = function(username,password) {
        var objectJson = {'username':username,'password':password}; 
        $http.post('/loginRequest',objectJson).success(function(response) {
        console.log("response: "+response);
      });
    };
});
```

server.js

```
// Listen for Seach collection request
router.post('/loginRequest', function (req, res, next) {
    var databaseName = "DB", collection = "Accounts";
    var username = req.body.username, password = req.body.password;
    var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        //var cursor = db.collection(collection).find( { "username":username,"password": password } );
        // cannot apply cursor methods to the result of findOne() because a single document is returned. 
        db.collection(collection).findOne({ "username": username, "password": password }, function (err, doc) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            if (doc != null) {
                console.log("Found");
                res.render('index', { title: 'Home Page', message: 'Message'});
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a AJAX call, you need to respond with a JSON but you are using res.render() that send a HTML.

angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.login = function(username, password) {
    var objectJson = {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    };
    $http.post('/loginRequest', objectJson).success(function(response) {
      location.href = '/';
    }, function () {
      alert('Invalid credentials');
    });
  };
});
```

node:

```
// Listen for Seach collection request
router.post('/loginRequest', function(req, res, next) {
  var databaseName = "DB";
  var collection = "Accounts";

  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  var db = new Db(databaseName, new Server('localhost', 27017));
  db.open(function(err, db) {
    db.collection(collection).findOne({
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    }, function(err, doc) {
      if(err) {
        throw err;
      }

      if (doc) {
        // Here also you need to set logged state in req.session
        // https://github.com/expressjs/session
        res.json(doc);

      } else {
        res.status(400).json();
      }

      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: How do i just open the jade page, instead of writing out the code             location.href = "/";

Comment: What? I think you are really mixing concerns here... You need to redirect to logged path using location.href. Also it's important to notice that you never saved the "logged" state in session, something like: req.session.user = doc or so

Comment: Yeah, you are right. For some reason i was worried about sending the link to the client via AngularJS, but thinking about it, there is nothing to worry about.